# MagicalRecord Can't access the properties of ManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I have set up the Core Data Stack by MagicalRecord using the method `-setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:`.

And I created the DataModel and a ManagedObject named *DriverOrder* with some attributes and created the SubClass of ManagedObject automatically like this

[image]

Later I write some codes to create a object and try to access the object in a ViewController class.

The code like this :

```
- (void)testCoreData {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
    DriverOrder *order = [DriverOrder MR_createEntityInContext:context];
    order.driverId = @"11";
    order.orderID = @(2015);

    DriverOrder *order2 = [DriverOrder MR_createEntityInContext:context];
    order2.driverId = @"15";
    order2.orderID = @(2016);

    [context MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
    NSArray *resultArr = [self fetchAllOrder];
    for (DriverOrder *theorder in resultArr) {
        DDLog(@"%@",theorder);
    }
}

- (NSArray *)fetchAllOrder {
    NSArray *orders = [DriverOrder MR_findAllSortedBy:@"orderID" ascending:YES];
    return orders;
}
```

UPDATES:

About the subclass of NSManagedObject, the DriverOrder was generated by Xcode **automatically** and I haven't do any thing about this class, it seems like this:

```
//
//  DriverOrder.h
//  
//
//  Created by lynulzy on 10/21/15.
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface DriverOrder : NSManagedObject

// Insert code here to declare functionality of your managed object subclass

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "DriverOrder+CoreDataProperties.h"



//
//  DriverOrder+CoreDataProperties.h
//  
//
//  Created by lynulzy on 10/21/15.
//
//
//  Choose "Create NSManagedObject Subclass…" from the Core Data editor menu
//  to delete and recreate this implementation file for your updated model.
//

#import "DriverOrder.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface DriverOrder (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *orderID;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *driverId;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

When I build and run the app ,questions come:

1. What's the path of the *.sqlite?
2. When I tried to get the properties of a fetched Object, the debug log looks something wrong 
   [image]
   and using getter method to access the debug log looks like this: [image]

Comment: This code is a mess and unreadable. you want people to help you, make sure you don't get crippled code postings. On a side note: show your NSManagedObject subclass for DriverOrder.

Comment: @Andy I just generate the DriverOrder by Xcode automatically and I have updated the code in my question description.THX

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you experience this because you've added new fields to your model and CoreData couldn't migrate data automatically.

When you develop an app and change your model frequently, you can pretty much ignore migrations and wipe out existing data.

I personally use something like this:

```
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];

#if DEBUG
    // Drop database on model mismatch during development
    [MagicalRecord setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:YES];
#endif
```

MagicalRecord automatically crafts URL for your database. If you use single persistent store, then to obtain the path to your SQL database you can use the following (after you initialize CoreData with MagicalRecord):

```
 NSLog(@"Persistent store URL: %@", [[NSPersistentStore MR_defaultPersistentStore] URL]);
```